# Can't use PHP inside script tag

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using JavaScript to `alert` out an **error**

If a user's input wrong and I put the code below:

```
<?php $_POST["usernamereg"] ?> = usernamereg;
```

the script won't alert anymore. If I remove it, then it can alert again.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var usernamereg;
var passwordreg;
var password2reg;
const regisForm =document.getElementById("reg-form");
function getValue(){
 usernamereg = document.getElementById("usernamereg").value;
passwordreg = document.getElementById("passreg").value;
password2reg = document.getElementById("pass2reg").value;
}
regisForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => { 
e.preventDefault();
getValue();


    if (usernamereg.length > 30 || usernamereg.length < 5){
        alert("Your username must be longer than 5 and less than 30"); 
        <?php $err = 1;?>;
    }else { 

        <?php $_POST["usernamereg"] ?> = usernamereg;
        <?php $err = 0;?>
    }

    if (passwordreg.length > 30 || passwordreg.length < 8){
        alert("Your password must be longer than 8 and less than 30"); 

        <?php $err = 1;?>
    } else {

          <?php $_POST["passreg"] ?> = passwordreg;

        <?php $err = 0;?>
    }
    if (password2reg!=passwordreg){
        alert("Your re-type password doesnt match");
        <?php $err = 1;?>
    }else {
          <?php $_POST["pass2reg"] ?> = password2reg;

        <?php $err = 0;?>
    }

});
</script>
```

Comment: You have to understand that javascript is executed on client side and php is executed on server side. The `$_POST` array will be accessible, after you 've sent the form to the server. You prevent the submission to the server with javascript and you 're trying to access the php `$_POST` array at the same time. This is not possible. You can try out HTML5 form validation with the constraint validation API or you 're submitting your data via AJAX request to your php request, wich answers asnychronously.

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo the value or you are trying to set nothing to the value of `password2reg`.

```
<?php echo $_POST["passreg"] ?> = passwordreg;
```

Note that this is likely not a great pattern as it is very error prone.

Comment: when i tried yours way, It did not add the value in the $_POST["passreg"]. I want to add the passwordreg to the $_POST["passreg"] . However. thanks for your reply

Comment: You are mixing up PHP (server side) and Javascript (client side). That can be a valid use case in some instances but sounds like not what you want to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

The code which you have written

```
<?php $_POST["usernamereg"] ?> = usernamereg;
```

you are trying to assign a javascript variable to PHP post variable.

This is not correct.

It would be better you could post your html form code because you don't need to set the `$_POST["usernamereg"]` because its already set when you submit the form.

If your username and password are correct then you just need to submit the form.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh thank you. I though that you can add the data from the script to the php